# How to do HTTP-request/call with JSON payload from command-line?

Tags: linux, json, command-line, web-crawler

What's the easiest way to do a JSON call from the command-line? I have a website that does a JSON call to retrieve additional data.

The **Request Payload** as shown in Google Chrome looks like this:

```
{"version": "1.1", "method":"progr","id":2,"params":{"call":...} }
```

It's about doing the call from (preferably) linux command line and retrieving the JSON content, not about parsing the incoming JSON data.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use curl, assuming the data is POST'ed, something like

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/some/path -d '{"version": "1.1", "method":"progr","id":2,"params":{"call":...} }'
```

If you're just retrieving the data with a GET , and don't need to send anything bar URL parameters,
you'd just run `curl http://example.com/some/path`

Comment: You may need `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` too

Comment: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type :-(

Answer (score 106):

You could use wget as well:

```
wget -O- --post-data='{"some data to post..."}' \
  --header='Content-Type:application/json' \
  'http://www.example.com:9000/json'
```

Calling `wget` with the option `-O` providing the `-` (space in between will be ignored, so it could also be written as `-O -`) to it as its value will cause `wget` to output the HTTP response directly to standard output instead into a file. The long option name for that is `--output-document=file`.

Comment: What is `-O-`? Is this a kebab? )

Comment: From the man page `-O file` is the shorthand option for `--output-document=file` and the dash (`-`) usually represents the file descriptor for standard out of the current tty.

It just means "print the result to the console instead of writing it to a file".

Comment: Thanks. My point is that this argument looks cryptic, I would suggest to add this explanation to the answer ;)

Comment: @SlavaFominII thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to contain an explanation about the `-O` option.

Answer (score 13):

You could use `wget` with `post-file` as well, which I found useful.

```
wget --post-file=[file] --header=Content-Type:application/json [URL]
```

You can keep the content in the file and the content will be sent as `post` data.

Answer (score 8):

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:8099/someservice/services/boo \
--header 'authorization: Basic dkfhsdlepwmdseA==' \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"value": "24.127.1212.123"}'
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)? It's very good at facilitating HTTP GET/POST requests via the command line.

e.g. (for a GET request):

```
C:\WINDOWS>curl "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitterapi&result_type=
popular"
{"results":[{"from_user_id_str":"32316068","profile_image_url":"http://a2.twimg.
com/profile_images/351010682/twitblock_profile_normal.png","created_at":"Thu, 25
 Nov 2010 14:37:46 +0000","from_user":"twitblockapp","id_str":"7805146834669569"
,"metadata":{"result_type":"popular","recent_retweets":10},"to_user_id":null,"te
xt":"blocking and reporting functions are currently failing. @TwitterAPI have be
en notified. http://j.mp/id5w3m","id":7805146834669569,"from_user_id":32316068,"
geo":null,"iso_language_code":"en","to_user_id_str":null,"source":"&lt;a href=&q
uot;http://twitter.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Tweetie for Mac&lt;/a&g
t;"}],"max_id":9607558079713280,"since_id":0,"refresh_url":"?since_id=9607558079
713280&q=twitterapi","results_per_page":15,"page":1,"completed_in":0.012698,"sin
ce_id_str":"0","max_id_str":"9607558079713280","query":"twitterapi"}
```